# How to make custom live bootable Debian Distribution

Tags: linux, debian, live, debian-buster, live-cd

i am new to this forum

i am a student , and a Debian 10 XFce user , I Want to create my own usb linux distribution with live boot capabilities ,

according to some methods , i have used Linux-live kit , from github
and also tried programs that offer live system creation,

but i am facing errors in every method ,,

according to initial steps, i have customised the OS and installed required programms

i request you to please guide me to make my own live bootable distro ,
OS- Debian 10 Buster XFCE

Thaknks
Ashutosh_7i

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There's other guides you can find on google more simple to build the kind of distro you are looking to make. I would suggest [this one](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/). It's the one I follow lately when I need to build a custom USB environment for fixing certain setups.

Comment: maaan , thanks man , this looks very promising , i will try it , again thaks